# How to get value generated with Javascript on $_POST method?

Tags: javascript, php

I have three textboxes Supplier's Price, Mark-up Price, and Total Price.
When I input value on both the Supplier's Price and Mark-Up price textboxes, the value on the Total Price's textbox will generate a value via JavaScript.

```
 $('#sell_price, #markup_price').on('input',function() {
   var sell_price = parseInt($('#sell_price').val());
   var markup_price = parseFloat($('#markup_price').val());
$('#total_price').val((sell_price  + ((markup_price/100)*100) ? sell_price + ((markup_price/100)*100) : 0).toFixed(2));
});
```

How do I get the Total Price's textbox value onto my $_POST?[image]

HTML Code

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
     <label for="">Supplier's Price</label>
     <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
         ₱
       </span>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="sell_price" id="sell_price" placeholder="Buying Price Per Unit" step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' required>

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
     <label for="">Mark-up Price (In Percentage)</label>
     <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
         %
       </span>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="markup_price" id="markup_price" placeholder="0" required min='1' max='100'>
     </div>
   </div>

       <div class="col-md-4">
        <br>
         <label for="">Total</label>
         <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon">
             %
           </span>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total_price" id="total_price" placeholder="0" disabled>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Please provide the html-code of the form.

Comment: The `#total_price` must not be `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

You can path :

```
$('#total_price').val
```

to this:

```
function post(path, parameters) {
var form = $('<form></form>');

form.attr("method", "post");
form.attr("action", path);

$.each(parameters, function(key, value) {
    var field = $('<input></input>');

    field.attr("type", "hidden");
    field.attr("name", key);
    field.attr("value", value);

    form.append(field);
});

// The form needs to be a part of the document in
// order for us to be able to submit it.
$(document.body).append(form);
form.submit();
}
```

Comment: onchange event of $('#total_price')